# R Sum columns by index

Tags: r

I need to find a way to sum columns by their index,I'm working on a big`read.csv` file, I'll show here a sample of the problem; I'd like for example to sum from the 2nd to the 5th and from the 6th to the 7h the following matrix:

```
a 1  3  3  4  5  6 
b 2  1  4  3  4  1 
c 1  3  2  1  1  5 
d 2  2  4  3  1  3
```

The result has to be like this:

```
a 11 11
b 10  5
c  7  6
d  8  4
```

The columns have all different names

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can use `rowSums` on the subset of columns i.e 2:5 and 6:7 separately and then create a new `data.frame` with the output.

```
data.frame(df1[1], Sum1=rowSums(df1[2:5]), Sum2=rowSums(df1[6:7]))
#  id Sum1 Sum2
#1  a   11   11
#2  b   10    5
#3  c    7    6
#4  d   11    4
```

Comment: I've only got one more question. Regarding the index i'm using the value of an array:
data.frame(Db2[1], Sum1=rowSums(Db2[reg[1]:reg[2]])
In order to have the correct position, but when i try to do this the system tells me:
 Error in reg[1]:reg[2] : argomento NA/NaN

Comment: @Fri That you should post as a separate question

Answer (score 3):

The package dplyr has a function exactly made for that purpose:

```
require(dplyr)
df1 = data.frame(a=c(1,2,3,4,3,3),b=c(1,2,3,2,1,2),c=c(1,2,3,21,2,3))
df2 = df1 %>% transmute(sum1 = a+b , sum2 = b+c) 
df2 = df1 %>% transmute(sum1 = .[[1]]+.[[2]], sum2 = .[[2]]+.[[3]])
```

Comment: can above solution be used in mass scale. For example, sum all columns from 11 to 31